# Can I have the GET_ACCOUNTS permission for just my app's own account?

Tags: android

Android's GET_ACCOUNTS() permission (and USE_CREDENTIALS) gives me access to all of the users accounts, but I'm only interested in the account that my own app creates. How can I avoid requesting permission for my app to to use unrelated accounts, and therefore giving the impression that my app might use those accounts.

Having to request these broad permissions seems like a heavy price to pay for just using the AccountManager system to store account details.